# if p is prime then 1920 divides $p^4-10p^2+9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

if $p>6$ is prime then 1920 divides $p^4-10p^2+9$
Take out the factors of 1920 which are $$1920=2^7(3)(5)$$
and factor the expression that remains as
$$p^4-10p^2+9=(p-3)(p-1)(p+1)(p+3)$$
and I assumed as p is prime then p-1 and p + 1 is even then it is divisible by $2^7$

but I think it is not correct, can you help me?

Comment: All of $p-3,p-1,p+1,p+3$ are even, and mod $8$ they must represent the residue classes $0,2,4,6$. That means their product must be divisible by $8\cdot2\cdot4\cdot2$, right?

Comment: ${\rm odd}^2\equiv 1\pmod{\!8}$ so $\,p^2\!-1=8j\Rightarrow p^2\!-9 = 8(j\!-\!1)\Rightarrow (p^2-1)(p^2-8) = 2^6\,\overbrace{\!j(j-1)}^{\rm\color{#c00}{even}}\qquad $

Comment: The prime $2$ is the hardest. Since $p$ is not divisible by $3$ either $p-1$ or $p+1$ must be. And you can argue similarly for $5$ [eg note that $\{p-3, p-1, p+1, p+3, p+5\}$ is a complete set of residues mod $5$ and $p+5$ is not divisible by five]

Answer (score 6):

- Since $p$ is prime greater than $3$ then $\gcd(p,3)=1$ and by little Fermat theorem we have $p^3\equiv p\pmod 3$

This allows us to reduce $p^4-10p^2+9\equiv p^2-10p^2+0\equiv -9p^2\equiv 0\pmod 3$

- Similarly $p^4\equiv 1\pmod 5$

This allows us to reduce $p^4-10p^2+9\equiv 1-0p^2-1\equiv 0\pmod 5$

- For the divisibility by $2^7$ your work is a good starting point

Let explicit $p=2k+1$ then $p^4-10p^2+9=16(k-1)k(k+1)(k+2)$

This is a multiple of $4$ consecutive numbers, so they belong to the set $\{4n,\ 4n+1,\ 4n+2,4n+3\}$ not necessarily in that order.

The product of the two $4n(4n+2)=16n^2+8n$ is divisible by $8$.

So overall the expression is divisible by $16\times 8=2^7$