# Let p>5 be the prime number. Prove that the expression $p^{4} - 10p^{2} +9$ is divisible by $1920$

Tags: linear-algebra, divisibility

I broke the given expression $p^{4} - 10p^{2} +9 as (p-3)(p+3)(p-1)(p+1)$ and now for all prime numbers grater than 5 the condition is true but I checked it by putting values.

Is there any proper or trick to prove this condition. I am trying.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if p is prime then 1920 divides $p^4-10p^2+9$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4113276/if-p-is-prime-then-1920-divides-p4-10p29)

Comment: NO, i can't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $5\nmid p$, we must have one of $p\equiv 1,2,3,4\equiv 1,-3,3,-1\pmod 5$, hence $(p-1)(p+3)(p-3)(p+1)$ is a multiple of $5$. Similarly, already $(p-19(p+1)$ is a multiple of $3$. As $1920=2^7\cdot 3\cdot 5$, we are left with showing a factor $2^7$. Well, as $p$ is odd, $p^2\equiv 1\pmod 8$, hence $p^2-1$ and $p^2-9$ are both multiples of $8$. Moreover, $p^2\equiv 1$ or $9\pmod {16}$, i.e., one of $p^2-1$, $p^2-9$ is in fact a multiple of $16$. So bombined we arrive at a multiple of $8\cdot 16=128$, as desired.

Comment: For $2^7$ an alternative method is to note that $p-3, p-1, p+1, p+3$ are four successive even numbers one of which must be divisible by $8$ and another by $4$ (because it will differ by $4$ from a multiple of $8$, depending on which one is the multiple of $8$)

Comment: It holds true for any odd integer that is not a multiple of 5, right? We don't need p being prime.

Comment: Typos: `(−19(+1)` I guess you meant; `(−1)(+1)` And: **bombined**